# complex sequences and their limits.

Tags: complex-analysis

Hey i want to learn complex analysis, and thought of some examples, such as: $\lim_{n\to\infty}i/n$. How would you approach that, since i is not real could we still think of it as a scalar such that the limit theorems are still valid, so we could say it is $0*i=0$? I could also think of taking the $|a_n|$ but i am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $i$ is a constant: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}i/n=i\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n=i\cdot 0=0$$

Comment: Since you trying to learn complex analysis, it would be best to start with the limit of complex sequences (as you have done), but it would be worth your while to look at definitions. The definitions and theorems related to complex sequences is very similar to that of real sequences. The differences begin to emerge when we start dealing with limits of functions and derivative of functions.